# How to create just one tapGestureRecognizer for several UILabels?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying (and failing) to create just one tapGestureRecognizer to use on several UILabels.

Right now I am creating for every label in viewDidLoad a separate tapGestureRecognizer and adding it to the appropriate label. I ran into this problem because every touch should obviously call a different function.

This is how I create them:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        //tapGestureRecognizer for buttonOne

        buttonOne.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let oneGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.buttonOneAction))
        buttonOne.addGestureRecognizer(oneGestureRecognizer)

        //tapGestureRecognizer for buttonTwo

        buttonTwo.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let twoGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.buttonTwoAction))
        buttonTwo.addGestureRecognizer(twoGestureRecognizer)

        ...
```

They work fine, but how and where could I create just one tapGestureRecognizer and add it in viewDidLoad to each label with a different action?

Comment: why don't you use buttons instead of labels?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in comments by @Duncan C you can switch the gesture recognizer view as follow:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [buttonOne, buttonTwo].forEach {
            $0?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            $0?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapGesture)))
        }
    }

    @objc func tapGesture(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let label = gesture.view as? UILabel else { return }
        switch label {
        case buttonOne: print("buttonOne")
        case buttonTwo: print("buttonTwo")
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...or you could switch on the labels as well. The stated goal, though, was to call a different method for each label.

Comment: I think switching the gesture it is much easier than hit testing

Comment: Yes, the sender is a gesture recognizer, but each gesture recognizer has a view property, which is the view it's attached to.

Comment: I agree with you. My suggestion of hit testing was a "if you really wanted to you could do it this way but WHY" sort of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just create one per label.

The alternative is to create a single tap gesture recognizer that you attach to the common superview of all target views, and write a BUNCH of code that does hit-testing to figure out if the tap landed on any of your labels, and if so, which one, and dispatches the desired method for that label.

However, that's the whole point of tap gesture recognizers. You'd probably spend several days developing a bunch of code that has no benefits over using multiple tap gesture recognizers.